# Sharepoint column field type changing from original Infopath form field type

Tags: sharepoint-2013, infopath

I have an Infopath form I promoted an element with an integer type to the SharePoint library where the saved forms are stored. I am finding that SharePoint is treating this field as a line of text instead of as number which I need as I would like to be able to use key filtering to help people look through the library. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Unpromote and reprobate InfoPath element after ensuring correct element type.